# Web scraping href link in Python with Beautifulsoup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to code a web scraping to obtain information of Linkedin Jobs post, including Job Description, Date, role, and link of the Linkedin job post. While I have made great progress obtaining job information about the job posts I'm currently stuck on how I could get the 'href' link of each job post. I have made many attempts including using class driver.find_element_by_class_name, and select_one method, neither seems to obtain the 'canonical' link by resulting none value. Could you please provide me some light?

This is the part of my code that tries to get the href link:

```
    import requests
    from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

    url = https://www.linkedin.com/jobs/view/manager-risk-management-at-american-express-2545560153?refId=tOl7rHbYeo8JTdcUjN3Jdg%3D%3D&trackingId=Jhu1wPbsTyRZg4cRRN%2BnYg%3D%3D&position=1&pageNum=0&trk=public_jobs_job-result-card_result-card_full-click

    reqs = requests.get(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(reqs.text, 'html.parser')
    urls = []
    for link in soup.find_all('link'):
       print(link.get('href'))
```

link: https://www.linkedin.com/jobs/view/manager-risk-management-at-american-express-2545560153?refId=tOl7rHbYeo8JTdcUjN3Jdg%3D%3D&trackingId=Jhu1wPbsTyRZg4cRRN%2BnYg%3D%3D&position=1&pageNum=0&trk=public_jobs_job-result-card_result-card_full-click

Picture of the code where the href link is stored
[image]

Comment: You have used `selenium`? Please share your attempt with it

Answer (score 0):

I think you were trying to access the `href` attribute incorrectly, to access them, use `object["attribute_name"]`.

this works for me, searching for just links where `rel = "canonical"`:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "https://www.linkedin.com/jobs/view/manager-risk-management-at-american-express-2545560153?refId=tOl7rHbYeo8JTdcUjN3Jdg%3D%3D&trackingId=Jhu1wPbsTyRZg4cRRN%2BnYg%3D%3D&position=1&pageNum=0&trk=public_jobs_job-result-card_result-card_full-click"

reqs = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(reqs.text, 'html.parser')
for link in soup.find_all('link', rel='canonical'):
    print(link['href'])
```

Answer (score 0):

The `<link>` has an attribute of `rel="canonical"`. You can use an [`[attribute=value]`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors) CSS selector: `[rel="canonical"]` to get the value.

To use a CSS selector, use the [`.select_one()`](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#css-selectors) method instead of `find()`.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "https://www.linkedin.com/jobs/view/manager-risk-management-at-american-express-2545560153?refId=tOl7rHbYeo8JTdcUjN3Jdg%3D%3D&trackingId=Jhu1wPbsTyRZg4cRRN%2BnYg%3D%3D&position=1&pageNum=0&trk=public_jobs_job-result-card_result-card_full-click"
reqs = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(reqs.text, 'html.parser')

print(soup.select_one('[rel="canonical"]')['href'])
```

Output:

```
https://www.linkedin.com/jobs/view/manager-risk-management-at-american-express-2545560153?refId=tOl7rHbYeo8JTdcUjN3Jdg%3D%3D&trackingId=Jhu1wPbsTyRZg4cRRN%2BnYg%3D%3D
```